# How to perform a numerical Laplace and inverse Laplace transforms in Matlab for a discrete input signal?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to evaluate the Laplace transform of a discrete stochastic signal I sample from a communication device.

As a simple test case I am trying to use the `ilaplace` to get the original signal, but I am not sure if my approach is plausible.

```
x = sym('x','real');
y = sym('y','real');
t=linspace(0,1000,1000);
f=sin(t);
s = x+i*y;               
F_s=sum(f.*exp(-s*t));   
ilaplace(F_s)
```

The above might seem silly, though in my real problem I am trying to estimate the medium [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) which is of the form`ilaplace(2*F_s/(-s*F_s +f(0)))`.

I have also tried to use a signal symbolic variable `s` and it gives me a train of deltas which I am not sure it's correct and what is the error estimation.

```
syms s;                                
F_s = symfun(sum(sin(t).*exp(-s*t)), s);
ilaplace(F_s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so that's the way I used matlab to do laplace transform for a discrete signal and recovered it back using ilaplace for validation purposes:

```
t=linspace(0,10,500);
f=exp(-t/0.2);   
syms s;                                
F_s = sum(f.*exp(-s*t));
f_t = (ilaplace(F_s)); 
F_t = (int(f_t));

y=subs(F_t,t);
Ft_recovered = diff(double(y));


subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,f)
title('numerical input exp(-t/0.2)')


subplot(2,2,2)
ezplot(F_s)
title('numerical laplace')


subplot(2,2,3)
plot(t(1:end-1), Ft_recovered)
title('recovered signal')


subplot(2,2,4)
syms x;
fx = symfun(exp(-x/0.2),x);
ezplot(laplace(fx))
title('symbolic laplace transform')
```

The big difficulty here is to make matlab to evaluate the sum of the dirac delta train, so I did this trick: integrated the expression to convert it to train of heaviside functions, evaluate it and then plot the derivative:

```
F_t = (int(f_t));
y=subs(F_t,t);
Ft_recovered = diff(double(y));
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing the number of elements in `t` to more accurately sample the sine function, or smoothing the signal before calculations. Another problem you face is that the inverse Laplace transform expects a function to be defined for `s>0`, i.e. up to infinity. You truncate your signal at `t=1000`, thus the Laplace transform is not going to infinity either.

Judging the [documentation of `ilaplace`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ilaplace.html?s_tid=doc_ta) it tries to transform *each individual term* in your array `F_s`. This has a sum of a thousand entries of some constant times some exponential of the form `exp(-s*t)`, whose inverse transform is a delta pulse, see [this Wikipedia page, second entry of the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms). Hence, your inverse transform of `F_s` is a series of a thousand delta pulses, which will presumably be exactly the thousand input points you generated with your `sin(t)`, up to some numerical error which emerged in the forward and backward Laplace transform.

Finally: MATLAB expects, as stated in the documentation, a single symbolic variable `s`. You made `s` consist of two symbolic variables. Whilst mathematically correct, MATLAB only takes the first symbolic variable to be the transform variable, thus you get an answer with delta pulses multiplied by some `exp(1i*y)` function. Using the following code, you at least get rid of that problem (but obviously keep the summation of delta pulses):

```
t=linspace(0,1000,1000);
f=sin(t);
syms s
F_s=sum(f.*exp(-s*t));   
ilaplace(F_s)
```

Comment: Is there a good way to estimate the error for a random input function?

Comment: @0x90 not sure; I've only done Laplace transforms by hand. What I can think of from the top of my head is using a least-squares solution to your input signal (which will presumably be a superposition of sines/cosines), and use the outcome of that as a symbolic input in `ilaplace`, thus giving it transformable *function* instead of *points*. There's probably better ways to do this though.